# Bit operations on MAC addresses in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, bit-manipulation, mac-address

I have a need to do certain bitwise comparisons of MAC addresses which I have stored in PostgreSQL as [`macaddr`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-net-types.html) types, but as far as I can tell there doesn't appear to be anything that would allow me to do this (short of parsing the MAC string into a hexadecimal number, which seems like it would not be very performant).

Does PostgreSQL have a way to efficiently do this sort of comparison, or to efficiently convert MAC addresses into a numeric or bit set representation that could then be compared?

The following works, but requires a fair bit of String manipulation to do so:

`select ('x'||replace(macaddr_field::varchar,':',''))::bit(48);`

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html

> The macaddr type also supports the standard relational operators (>,
>   <=, etc.) for lexicographical ordering, and the bitwise arithmetic
>   operators (~, & and |) for NOT, AND and OR.

these are your limits for bitwise operations with macaddr, eg:

```
t=# with mac(a,b) as
(values('01:00:00:ff:aa:78'::macaddr,'0e:7e:e9:f0:fa:80'::macaddr))
select a|b, ~ a, a&b, a <= b  from mac;
     ?column?      |     ?column?      |     ?column?      | ?column?
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------
 0f:7e:e9:ff:fa:f8 | fe:ff:ff:00:55:87 | 00:00:00:f0:aa:00 | t
(1 row)
```

works as promissed and you don't have to cast `macaddr` to `bit`, the rest depends on what kind of comparison you want to perform